# is pop or push to tuple Invalid in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, tuples

e.g.

```
let tuple: [string, number];
// the tuple is working
tuple = ["this is string type!", 123456];
tuple.pop();
// ["this is string type!"]
// now , tuple is only 1 item , type like be broken.
console.log(tuple);
tuple.push("this is string type?");
// ["this is string type!","this is string type?"]
// string into number item
console.log(tuple);
```

push and pop method is not keep tuple specific positions.
this is bug ? or features ?

Comment: It's a missing feature. There is an open feature request at [ms/TS#40316](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40316) to prohibit operations that violate tuple constraints.  Unfortunately this probably can't be adopted because currently tuples are considered assignable to array types, and fixing this would break lots of real world code that is perfectly safe (most people do not try to push/pop/unshift/shift/splice tuples).  Does that address your question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am Imissing?